# Migrate from JavaScript to Python on Google Apps

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script

I've inherited a fairly complex Googledoc spreadsheet with some scripted functionality implemented in the Google App Engine. The original coder used the JavaScript environment. Personally, I'm more comfortable with Python and I'm running into all kinds of weird errors on the JavaScript environment.

I'd like to just scrap what we have and rewrite the same scripts in Python, an exercise in translation, if you will...I'm wondering if there's a way to do that keeping the original spreadsheet so I don't have to recreate all the existing spreadsheet structure (several tabs, each with built-in conditional formatting, filters, etc. not to mention a length and complex submission form).

So, in short, I'd like to switch from JavaScript to Python in GAE -- is it possible? If so, how? If not, is there a way to copy the whole spreadsheet but start fresh with a blank Python script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Google App Engine, or Google Apps Script?

Comment: Wasn't aware there's a difference, but I guess I'm using Google Apps Script. I get to the editor by opening my spreadsheet, then going to Scripts -> Script Editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, the JavaScript-like language is the only one offered for Google Apps Script.

You seem to have confused it with Google App Engine, which is a platform-as-a-service that you can use to write your own applications, and offers Java, Python, and Go runtime environments. It is not a scripting language for Google Apps products such as Docs spreadsheets; that's what Apps Script is for.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Clearly I was confused about Google's offerings in this area. Thanks, Taymon!